# Prestashop 1.7.6.9 display default category_name into email and backoffice order

Tags: prestashop

I need to show:

- "default category name" of the purchased products into email template
- order_conf "default category name" of the purchased products into
  backoffice > single order (where at the moment it shows product_name + reference)
  [BO > orders > order > purchased product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN3IE.png)

Would you give me some indication on the files to be modified to show the category name (default_category) of the purchased products?

I have searched around the web but I can't find any solution / instructions to do this

Thanks to anyone who will be able to help me

Prestashop 1.7.6.9

Answer (score 0):

To show info in back office order detail you can use hook displayAdminOrderLeft.

For more info look at https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/

For mail you must change order_conf.html in mails directory.
To put extra data in template vars you can use actionEmailAddBeforeContent hook.

Comment: Thankyou Fran Cerezo for the indication to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Fran Cerezo for the indication to investigate.

To show Default Category name into hook "displayAdminOrderLeft", i opened

/admin123456/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_product_line.tpl file

So i added

{if isset($product.id_category_default)}
{assign var='catname' value=Category::getCategoryInformations(array($product.id_category_default))}
{$catname[$product.id_category_default].name}
{/if}

Otherwise, to show the "default category name" in the order confirmation email (for single product purchased) I'm in trouble ..

The /mails/it/order_conf.html file declares the {products} variable.
Where do I find the template to edit the {products} variable and then add the category name information?

Where is the reference file located?

Thanks

[{products variable into order_conf.html}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwKtY.jpg)

Comment: SOLVED. File responsable about {products} into email is located in -> /mails/en/order_conf_product_list.tpl